# How to secure wireless (Wi-Fi) home network

Tags: network, wifi

What are the countermeasures to make home wireless network secure, which will both prevent others from **stealing internet** and will also prevent **hackers** from taking control of computers through your own wireless network.

Comment: Humph... What have your Internet search yielded so far? Keeping the router up-to-date, changing default passwords, having strong passwords for all the stuff? By the way, voting to close as too broad.

Comment: I've got to go with @DeerHunter on this one. Although your question is straight forward, too many answers can be considered correct. This question is simply too broad for this forum. I hope my answer helps you, but without knowing specifically what you are looking for, it is difficult to answer.

Comment: This is rather a basic network configuration question to ask here: http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Set a strong password.

Yeah, this may seem common knowledge, but I actually stick with something unique, alphanumeric, and not the default router password.

2) Hope that whoever wants into your network doesn't have something like [Aircrack-ng](http://aircrack-ng.org/).

Aircrack is a network software suite consisting of a detector, packet sniffer, WPA/WPA-2-PSK and WEP cracker and analysis tool for 802.11 wireless LANs.

I've had friends in college that got good with this software, and you can get access to pretty much anyone's Wi-Fi network. All you need is to sniff the right packets (i.e. the password) and you're good to go.

4) Restart your router & change your password regularly.

Just restarting your router can terminate sessions from un-authorized users, then if you are paranoid, just go into the router and change the password. Doing this every 90 days or so is just healthy, much like your PC or any other device.

5) Limit physical access to your router / APs.

If you have physical access to an AP or router, it can be easier to get into your network. So goes the phrase - if I can touch it, it's mine. Keep it behind a lock and key if you can. I can't tell you how many times I have gone to a Wi-Fi AP and the password (key) is printed on a label on the bottom. (NOTE: you don't need to worry about this if you change the default password.)

6) Change your router's Administrator password.

Once you are in your router (via browser - normally 192.168.0.1) you need to change the default password for admin access. This will keep others on your network out of your router, and can ensure that you remain in control of your network. Keep this password unique from the other password(s) on your network, and change it every once in a while - if you want.

7) Realize that no network (even more so a WLAN) can be secure.

If you are using Wi-Fi, you need to accept the fact that it is far less secure than a wired Ethernet connection, and there is no such thing as a secure network - anywhere.

Comment: I will also suggest changing the default SSID, not a big deal but it is still a bit of useful information, (not that the mac address wont tell me the details i want to know)..

Comment: Another good countermeasure is to not broadcast your beacons, this pretty much makes you imune to aircarck war driving type attacks.

Comment: @EricN: this is false security. Any automatic attack tool will discover your wireless network name within a few seconds (unless you turned it off).

Comment: It's not false security, it's mitigation and obfuscation.  Avoiding an attack altogether is even better than making use of the security mechanisms in place.